# How to check if value from one column exist in the second column in Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

I have some values in column A and I want to check one by one if the values in column A exist in column B.

Answer (score 0):

Send the same file to both inputs of the Find/Replace too, and:

- select to match Entire field
- choose column A as "Find with Field"
- choose column B as "Find Value"
- "Append Fields to Record" choose Column B.

This will add a 2nd column B to your data set, which will be NOT NULL if an instance of column B exists that matches a given column A.

Answer (score -1):

You could also accomplish this in much the same way with the join tool.  Import data twice, select tool to isolate each column, do a join with column a = column b.  This will give you output showing which values are in both columns, as well as giving you the unique values from each column.  Just depends on what you're trying to accomplish later down the workflow.

Here is an image depicting this [workflow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yU2U.jpg)